# Boto3 read from Kinesis stream at timestamp

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to read from a Kinesis stream. It works fine if I use the `ShardIteratorType` `AT_SEQUENCE_NUMBER` or `LATEST`. However if I try to use the `AT_TIMESTAMP` type and set a `TIMESTAMP`, boto3 complains:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/validate.py", line 269, in serialize_to_request
    raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "Timestamp", must be one of: StreamName, ShardId, ShardIteratorType, StartingSequenceNumber
```

The code to to get the `shard_id` is the following.

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime

client = boto3.client('kinesis')

shard_it = client.get_shard_iterator(
    StreamName='foo',
    ShardId='shardId-000000000000',
    ShardIteratorType='AT_TIMESTAMP',
    Timestamp=datetime(2015, 1, 1)
)
```

Has anyone had experience with this?

According to the [API docs](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/kinesis.html#client) the parameter exists.

Comment: On second thought, your boto3 does not seem to be up to date. Please run $ sudo pip install -U boto3.

Comment: Thanks @quiver! The reason was that my `boto3` version was outdated. The timestamp that I passed was valid. Feel free to edit your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @ ustroetz updated the answer! Glad you made it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your `boto3` is not up-to-date, so boto3 client library cannot recognise new parameters. Please run `$ sudo pip install -u boto3` or the like.

By the way, `Timestamp` parameter accepts both of the following:

- datetime object(e.g. `datetime.datetime`)
- UNIX timestamp(e.g. `time.time`)